# Salesforce retirement from v21.0 to v30.0, generated ApiTotalUsage file from eventlog files, how to know where the resource is used

Tags: rest, soap, bulk

I have generated ApiTotalUsage file from eventlog files.

I followed the steps mentioned in this article and generated the ApiTotalUsage file

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1

how to know where the Api resources is used like Apex Rest Api or Bulk Api or Installed package...etc.

Comment: Ideally, you have designated dedicated users for each integration - that helps enormously in traceability

Answer (score 1):

Soap, REST & Bulk API are standard so there in no place in Salesforce where you can find which application is calling them.

All you can do it investigate the softwares behind IPs that are calling these APIs

You can find tutorial & examples in [this article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/handle-salesforce-api-versions-deprecation-like-a-pro-335065f52238)